# Android: AutoCompleteTextView top margin ListView

Tags: android, listview, margin, padding, autocompletetextview

The AutoCompleteTextView displays a ListView in a popup for auto completion. On top of the popup, before the ListView begins, there ist a little margin, in effect the first line in ListView looks higher than the other entries. Is there a way to remove the margin. For me it is just a problem because a changed the "dropDownVerticalOffset" of the AutoCompleteTextView to be on bottom of the TextView, otherwise there is negative offset and you don't see the difference if height of the first line.

How can I remove this margin?

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Can you post an image, so I can get it clearly, coz I checked an image from [this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/auto-complete-text-view-android.html) blog and there's nothing I feel like what you've explained here

Answer (score 0):

Try to add XML attribute to your AutoCompleteTextView:

```
android:popupBackground="color_what_you_want_to_background"
```

Hope, it helps you